# Why is my census badge missing?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, badges, survey-2018

I spent quite some time in filling out the developer survey. When I checked the results yesterday, it said on the bottom that the participants with valid answers would be rewarded the census badge. However, I didn't seem to get one as it doesn't show on my profile. 
Did something go wrong? I even received the "[Just Released] The 2018 Developer Survey Results" email which states that

> "You're receiving this email because you took the annual developer survey and opted in to receive research invitations."

Was my response invalid because I went through some network changes while I answered it? Thanks in advance!